# Is there any other way to upload file in web page without using AutoIt in webdriver framework

Tags: selenium-webdriver, robotframework, autoit

We are looking for a way to upload images/files in webpage where our automation framework is Selenium Web driver [Robot framework] and we are using AutoIt to do the same.
When we are using auto-it we are kept on observing corrupted issues. Looking for some one's support to overcome this,

Comment: What's the reason you're using AutoIt, but not the standard selenium functionality/Robotframework keyword `Choose File`?

Comment: Did you try- Choose File id=id-of-file-upload  absolute-path-of-file-to-be-uploaded

Comment: At [so] we try to help people with their programming difficulties. This requires some form of code example to work with. Can you describe what you've tried and what describe to us the expected and observed outcome? This prevents us from guessing and provides you with a more specific response from our end.

Comment: for using "Choose File" selenium keyword, we would need a proper id/class/atleast xpath for the browse path, in our case we do not have an id for browse path. so thats the reason we are using Auto it)

Comment: Kootstra,we are using AutoIT Library Keywords of Robot framework to upload file/image in GUI, Keywords are like "Win Wait Active", "Control Set Text",  "Control Focus" etc. when we are using these things in keyword/test case level we are facing different  issue , below is the trac
Initializing test library 'AutoItLibrary' with no arguments failed: com_error: (-2147024703, 'OLE error 0x800700c1', None, None)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\AutoItLibrary\__init__.py", line 79, in __init__
    self._AutoIt = win32com.client.Dispatch("AutoItX3.Control")

Answer (score 0):

You can use the keyword Choose File for File uploading in Robot Framework.

Syntax:

```
Choose File   locator   file_path
```

Example:

```
Choose File   my_upload_field   ${CURDIR}/trades.csv
```

For more details you can use [this link](http://robotframework.org/Selenium2Library/Selenium2Library.html#Choose%20File)